# Error: Failed to lookup view "about" in views directory "views"

Tags: handlebars.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// set static folder
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//set handlebars middleware
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs'
  })
  
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', 'views')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home.hbs');
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.get('/views/layouts/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about');
});
```

I cannot to configure page ABOUT I get en error: Error: Failed to lookup view "about" in views directory "views".
Home page is working

help and answers, solve my problem

Comment: Do you have an `about.hbs` file and is it in the same directory as `home.hbs`?

Comment: no, it is directory  '/views/layouts/about.hbs
'home' in /views/

Comment: `about.hbs` should not be under `layouts/`, it should be in the same folder as `home.hbs`.

Comment: I get Cannot GET /views/layouts/about
I wrote this:
app.get('/about.hbs', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about');
});

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to do. The .hbs files are not intended to be downloaded directly; they are supposed to be compiled and rendered into an HTTP response body. I don't understand why you are creating handlers for requests of `/views`. `/views` is not intended to be public.